# Vectorized R function

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I have to write a vectorized R function f that takes a vector x= (x_1, . . . , x_m) and a natural number n, and returns the value f_n(x) given by:

[image]

Example:

```
> x = seq(-1, 3, by = 0.4)
> f(x,6)   # here n=6

[1] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
[4] 2.666667e-06 6.480000e-04 8.333333e-03
[7] 4.430667e-02 1.410800e-01 3.050933e-01
[10] 4.755467e-01 5.500000e-01
```

This is what I got:

```
f = function(x, n){
  s = 0
  for(j in 0:x)
    s = s + (-1)^j*choose(n, j)*(x-j)^(n-1)
  s/factorial(n-1)
}

x = seq(-1, 3, by = 0.4)
f(x,6)

Warning in 0:x: numerical expression has 11 elements: only the first used
[1] -8.333333e-03 -6.480000e-04 -2.666667e-06 2.666667e-06 6.480000e-04
[6] 8.333333e-03 4.481867e-02 1.574640e-01 4.294693e-01 9.901147e-01
[11] 2.025000e+00
```

Clearly it is not what it should be in the example. What did I do wrong here? TIA

EDIT: Maybe using `outer` and `apply` might help with `x`?

Comment: In your image of the definition, the sum goes from 0 to x. In your code it goes from 0 to n. Also in your code x is rational? That seems unusual for this kind of definitions.

Comment: @AEF I have changed for(j in 0:n) to for(j in 0:x), however the result is still off.

Comment: What would be the expected result?

Comment: @AEF The same as in the example

Comment: Regarding x: It would have expected it to be integer and not rational. The problem is that we don't know the domain of j. So i would say your definition of the function is incomplete, we need at least additional information about the domain of j.

Comment: @AEF From my understanding j is up to x and if x is a vector then it can be different for each element of x.

Comment: Yes, but is it integer? Assuming it is, please show how you have adapted your code for the sum to go to x and not to n. because the code you have will absolutely not work if x is  vector and the sum goes to x.

Comment: @AEF I don't know how. If I knew I'd be solving this lol. The definition of the image the sum goes from 0 to x,  and x is a vector. How do I solve this?

Comment: Am I assuming correctly that this is your homework? Hint: You need to loop over x and set `j <- 0 : floor(x)`.

Comment: @Roland should I loop over x by the end? So after the first for loop. And do for (j in x) { j <- 0 : floor(x) } ? Is that correct?

Comment: Ok I figured apparently using outer() and apply() functions might work. But I am not sure how do I use them here.

Comment: You don't need your current loop as you can do this fully vectorized for one x value using `sum`. I suggest you write first a working solution for one x value. Than you can wrap that in a `vapply` loop.

Comment: @Roland I understood I could wrap it up with vapply but how do you do this for one x value using sum?

Comment: Well, since this is homework, I won't help further. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slightly different way of doing this solely based on base R:

```
x = seq(-1, 3, by = 0.4)
n <- 6

fn <- function(x, n) {
  x[x <= 0] <- 0
  sapply(x, function(x) {
    Reduce(function(a, b) {
      a + (-1) ^ b * (factorial(n)/(factorial(b) * factorial(n-b))) * (x - b) ^ (n-1)
    }, seq(0, x), init = 0) * (1/factorial(n-1))
  })
}

fn(x, 6)

 [1] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 2.666667e-06 6.480000e-04 8.333333e-03 4.430667e-02
 [8] 1.410800e-01 3.050933e-01 4.755467e-01 5.500000e-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It can be modified to become tidier but maybe it can solve your problem in its current form. I used both base R and `purr` functions for iteration instead of `for` loop but maybe `for` loop alone can do the job.

```
library(tidyverse)
n <- 6
x <- seq(-1, 3, by = 0.4)
x[x<= 0] <- 0
seq_fun <- function(x) seq(0, x)
d <- sapply(x, seq_fun)
fun <- function(r, t) {
   sum((-1) ^ r *choose(n, r)*(r-t)^(n-1)) / factorial(n - 1)
}
as_vector(map2(d, x, fun))
```

Comment: The code works, however is there a way to keep it in the format that x = seq(-1, 3, by = 0.4) and f(x,6) at the end? So we run  > x = seq(-1, 3, by = 0.4) then > f(x,6), and finally we get the sequence

Comment: Yes you can define a new function f and put the whole code chunk inside f. Now you can call this function by f(x, n). If it is not clear I can edit the answer to implement this.